# Spring Boot application gives "405 method not supported" exception for only Angular/HTML/JSP resources

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I have an application written with Spring Boot and AngularJS. When I try to hit a REST service as part of this application, I am able to hit it with POST method wherever POST is configured for request mapping.

But if I try to request AngularJS bind pages, I get a "405 method not supported" exception. So I try to create HTML and JSP pages too, which are not bound to Angular but still, I am getting the same exception.

Where can I start debugging this, and what is the likely reason?

Comment: pls edit to include code snippets

Comment: share your controller that you make a call and related entity.

Comment: I will try to format code so that i will not get into legal issues to share some snippet but i am sharing here furthere details about issue.

Answer (score 0):

i am sharing here furthere details about issue. 
Basically this existing application created/developed with Jhipster, angularjs, Spring boot  and spring security does not allow to access html/angularjs related resources with POST from outside. I will explain here what different scenarios work and what is not not working. 1.Postman trying to access base url trying to fetch index.html from same application- Give 405 Post method not allowed.2.Created an independent Test.html in same application and trying to access it from postman- Gives 405 Post method not allowed.3.Created a service which allows POST access in same application- Able to hit service from WSO2 IS IDP and also from Postman.4.Created a separate application on tomcat and provided as callback in WSO2 IDP with starting point for SSO from base url of existing application- Able to hit callback URL on tomcat server. Firefox shows that a POST request was generated for callback URL from WSO2 IS IDP to tomcat based application 5.Created a separate application with Angular js and Spring boot  and provided as callback in WSO2 IDP with starting point for SSO from base url of existing application- Able to hit callback URL on tomcat server. Firefox shows that a POST request was generated for callback URL from WSO2 IS IDP to new application with Spring boot and Angularjs. This took me down to conclusion that one of three is causing this issue
1.  Spring security  generated from JHipster 
2.  Angularjs 
3.  Some CORS or other filter from Spring Security is causing this issue.

Till now we have tried to different debugging methods like 
1.  disable CORS,
2.   in angularjs-resource.js enable POST for get operation, 
3.  In SecurityCOnfigurer, try to permit POST method for base URL or resolve it to GET in httpsercurity authorizerequest etc.
4.  Also ignoring resources in websecurity.

Application stack for existing application which we are trying to implement SSO is as below
1.  Angularjs 1.5.8
2.  Springboot 1.5.9.release
3.  WSO2IS 5.4.1 
4.  WSO2AM 2.1.0
5.  JHipster

Let me know if any particular area which we might have missed to analyze or different methods to try.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable CSRF in security config

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        ...
    }
    ...
}

@SpringBootApplication
@Import({
        ...
        SecurityConfig.class
        ...
})
public class SpringBootApp {
    ...
}
```